# Routing a folder to another URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, routes

I Recently migrated a website from PHP to rails. NEwt to the website they was a wordpress that is staying. the urls were as follow :

```
www.thedomain.com /      #former PHP now rails
www.thedomain.com/blog/   #the wordpress.
```

now that the website is in Rails, i cannot just put a php wordpress in the blog folder.

I tried to go to a blog.thedomain.com solution using thoses route (actual domain names i use in dev as i am trying to make it work) :

```
namespace :blog do
    match'', to: redirect {|params,request| "http://blog.fakefake1111/#{params[:path]}#{request.path}"}, via: :all
    match '*path', to: redirect {|params,request| "http://blog.fakefake2222/#{params[:path]}"}, via: :all
  end
```

It doesnt quite work, as the params are ignored and the first one add /blog/ at the end of the URL.

How can i make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I will use the alias capability of apache to do it. I do not really need to use rails for that.